# Undefined variable: compilation errors in Foundation 5 Sass project

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to build my first Foundation 5 project, and am new to CSS frameworks. I've successfully created a Sass project using the Foundation CLI, and when I hit index.html in the browser it all looks fine with Foundation 5 styling.

My /scss folder has 2 files, _settings.scss and app.scss which is simply

```
@import "settings";
@import "foundation";
```

This is the order recommended on ZURB forums. At this point, I thought you could start amending _settings.scss to customise things, but every time I uncomment a line in the file I get

**error scss/app.scss (Line 47 of scss/_settings.scss: Undefined variable: "$font-weight-normal".)**

type warnings from Compass. Why are the global variables undefined?

From the docs, these basic Sass variables are held in the _global.scss partial. I've checked my project and they are indeed defined there - so why do we

```
@import "settings";
```

before we

```
@import "foundation";
```

?? Any help with getting up and running greatly appreciated. I've not touched any of the Foundation files held in bower_components, just trying to amend _settings.scss in the /scss directory (which seems to be what you are supposed to do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncomment global variable `$font-weight-normal`
It's in [_settings.scss](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/_settings.scss) line 44

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked my _settings.scss and there was no such declaration on line 44...in fact no declaration for `$font-weight-normal` anywhere in the entire file. I've checked the latest version on GitHub and that line is there - odd that a project built using Foundation CLI isn't using the correct files, very frustrating. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!

Comment: Is this a bug in Foundation CLI? I have all the latest versions of Node, Ruby, Git, NPM and Bower...

Comment: @drjimmie1976 Looks like a bug. Sass version has the same problem.